# How to display MiniBufExpl window on the top

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

instead of the default display of the MiniBufExpl window on the bottom, I would like to have it on the top, is this possible?

Comment: Can you link to the plugin? Have you tried asking the maintainers? Have you read the help for the plugin or browsed its code to see if there’s a way to configure it? You can always use `<C-w>K` to move a window to the top

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you'll find the plugin [here](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim). I've checked the Readme as well as the [docs](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/blob/master/doc/minibufexpl.txt) but could not find it. I did not check the code itself though. Wasn't aware of `<C-w>K`, this is good to know, thanks! Nice that the command works with all navigation keys `H,J,K,L` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the docs:

```
To control where the new split window goes relative to the current window, use
the setting:

  let g:miniBufExplBRSplit = 0   " Put new window above
                                 " current or on the
                                 " left for vertical split
  let g:miniBufExplBRSplit = 1   " Put new window below
                                 " current or on the
                                 " right for vertical split
```

So set it to 0 and you should be good.

Comment: ou man, I either need glasses or some serious rewiring...
Thanks!

Comment: np! @Wolfson sometimes it just takes another eye

Comment: @D.BenKnoble So 3 eyes then? 